# react native expo - I updated to version 46 of the expo and now to run eas build of the problem

Tags: react-native, expo, build.gradle

```
[stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.688[stderr] * What went wrong:689[stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseAarMetadata'.690[stderr] > Multiple task action failures occurred:691[stderr]    >692[stderr] A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction693[stderr]       > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a694[stderr]         dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)695[stderr]         is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).696[stderr]         Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1.697[stderr]         AAR metadata file: /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/3674e27d37b475f0683f7bbbe8303cb5/transformed/appcompat-1.4.1/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.698[stderr]    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction699[stderr]       > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a700[stderr]         dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)701[stderr]         is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).702[stderr]         Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1.703[stderr]         AAR metadata file: /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7ab77f625091001fc32223f9fb565db7/transformed/jetified-appcompat-resources-1.4.1/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.704[stderr]    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction705[stderr]       > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a706[stderr]         dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)707[stderr]         is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).708[stderr]         Dependency: androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.1.709[stderr]         AAR metadata file: /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/813db86371a243b58f0ff2a909b3f176/transformed/jetified-fragment-ktx-1.4.1/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.710[stderr]    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction711[stderr]       > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a712[stderr]         dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)713[stderr]         is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).714[stderr]         Dependency: androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.4.0.715[stderr]         AAR metadata file: /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b5c2747e02192f8a24204359d209ab9d/transformed/jetified-activity-ktx-1.4.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.716[stderr]    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction717[stderr]       > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a718[stderr]         dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)719[stderr]         is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).720[stderr]         Dependency: androidx.fragment:fragment:1.4.1.721[stderr]         AAR metadata file: /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4b42d655655a38c51b61181b7f4b44cc/transformed/fragment-1.4.1/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.722[stderr]    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction723[stderr]       > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a724[stderr]         dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)725[stderr]         is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).726[stderr]         Dependency: androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views-helper:1.0.0.727[stderr]         AAR metadata file: /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d4cddcaf6e32293dca466443b146c652/transformed/jetified-emoji2-views-helper-1.0.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.728[stderr]    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction729[stderr]       > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a730[stderr]         dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)731[stderr]         is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).732[stderr]         Dependency: androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.0.0.733[stderr]         AAR metadata file: /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/38729e149656c0c85c7f2acce0c9dafa/transformed/jetified-emoji2-1.0.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.734[stderr]    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction735[stderr]       > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a736[stderr]         dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)737[stderr]         is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).738[stderr]         Dependency: androidx.activity:activity:1.4.0.739[stderr]         AAR metadata file: /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/f9b16bc23b60c87633182d0f3b862307/transformed/jetified-activity-1.4.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.740[stderr]    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction741[stderr]       > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a742[stderr]         dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)743[stderr]         is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).744[stderr]         Dependency: androidx.core:core:1.7.0.745[stderr]         AAR metadata file: /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d9763394d7a2747fce682fa75f371244/transformed/core-1.7.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.746[stderr]    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction747[stderr] > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a748[stderr]         dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)749[stderr]         is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).750[stderr]         Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.4.0.751[stderr]         AAR metadata file: /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2c63e08ad52ed05d2de70ae87b56f471/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-process-2.4.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.752[stderr]    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction753[stderr]       > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a754[stderr]         dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)755[stderr]         is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).756[stderr]         Dependency: androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.2.757[stderr]         AAR metadata file: /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/58c659e44b5c806a9a185c20a705beca/transformed/room-runtime-2.4.2/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.758[stderr]    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction759[stderr]       > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a760[stderr]         dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)761[stderr]         is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).762[stderr]         Dependency: androidx.sqlite:sqlite-framework:2.2.0.763[stderr]         AAR metadata file: /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/f216fbfc86c0ee20eb02ba17f4047c4f/transformed/sqlite-framework-2.2.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.764[stderr]    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction765[stderr]       > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a766[stderr]         dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)767[stderr]         is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).768[stderr]         Dependency: androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.2.0.769[stderr]         AAR metadata file: /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/ea7f145a1745e02f67969c1f56135568/transformed/sqlite-2.2.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.770[stderr]    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction771[stderr]       > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a772[stderr]         dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)773[stderr]         is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).774[stderr]         Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.4.0.775[stderr]         AAR metadata file: /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/96a6fc2a6feb38f2bb5bdc9211883217/transformed/lifecycle-runtime-2.4.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.776[stderr] * Try:777[stderr] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.778[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org779[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 3m 53s78063 actionable tasks: 63 executed781Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

[image]

I need to build the project. I tried some similar troubleshooting I found on
I got this error log there on the expo website

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I run this comand line and had success.

```
expo prebuild -p android --clean
```